# Upserting a DataTable via a proc call C#

Tags: c#, datatable, proc, sqldataadapter

I have the following lines of code that call a proc and return the results of the proc call and place them into a DataTable

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter data = new SqlDataAdapter();

_repo.ExecuteSprocPopulateDataTable(command, null, dt);
```

When I debug my code, my datatable is populated with the results as expected but I'm stuck on passing the data back up in to my database via another proc.

I've looked and seen some stuff about SqlDataAdapters and tried the following line:

```
data.Update(dt.DataSet, _command);
```

But when I do, it tells me that `Value can not be null` which relates to my dataset.

Can someone advise the best way for me to upsert my data via a proc call?

Comment: are you asking how to use table valued parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what that _command there is, but with SqlDataAdapters, updates typically go like this:

```
try
{
    using (SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(data))
    {
        data.InsertCommand = cb.GetInsertCommand();
        data.UpdateCommand = cb.GetUpdateCommand();
        data.DeleteCommand = cb.GetDeleteCommand();
        data.Update(dt);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // handle errors
}
```